# python3 easy way to ignore a blank value

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a project where I need to parse a YAML file and write it's contents in another file. Now, the key value can be blank, and in that case, the value is supposed to be ignored, i.e., should not be written in the file. I can write an "if statement" checking whether the value is blank and writing in the file only if it is isn't, but is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `if` to filter empty keys is the 'normal' way to achieve this.

You could use an `if` as part of a dictionary comprehension to remove all keys with empty values in a single step, and then use this new dictionary.

```
import yaml

with open("my.yaml") as yaml_f:
    data = {k: v for k, v in yaml.safe_load(yaml_f.read()).items() if v}
```

Of course this is just an alternative way of writing the full loop:

```
data = {}
with open("my.yaml") as yaml_f:
    for k, v in yaml.safe_load(yaml_f.read()).items():
    if v:
        data[k] = v
```

Note - there are ways to set up the `yaml` module to modify the resulting dictionary generated from the yaml file - however this requires the use of tags in the yaml. For example:

```
import yaml

my_yaml = """
--- !MyTag
a: 1
b: 2
c: ""
"""

def constructor_none(loader, node):
    return {k: v for k, v in loader.construct_mapping(node).items() if v}

yaml.add_constructor('!MyTag', constructor_none)

yaml.safe_load(my_yaml)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```